# How to apply check on Horizontal Div Scroll using buttons(Image)?

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I have three div

1. Previous Button(Image)
2. Container(Content)
3. Next Button(Image)

If I click on `previous` or `next` image it is scrolling fine.
If I click on `next` button scrolling stops at last element but the same is not working for previous button.
Means If I click on Previous Button the scroll should stop at first element but it is going ahead.

Link for the question [[fiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/cNmhR/137/):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the scrolling to stop at first element, you should set the `marginLeft` to `0` instead of `100px` on left.click which is causing that gap at the left.

However, this approach isn't ideal to create a slide-by-slide scroller, I'm guessing the current implementation just enables the user to scroll to either the first or the last element. It should scroll by the amount equal to width of each slide on each prev/next click until the first or the last element is reached.

Comment: @vishnu do you have link to demos to other approaches which enable `scroll by the amount equal to width of each slide on each prev/next click until the first or the last element is reached.`

Comment: you can use jquery plugins like [flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) or [anythingslider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) etc for this, their inbuilt css styles could also help you out a bit with the layout/visuals, other than these, one relevant tutorial that I could find is [here](http://webdeveloperpost.com/Articles/Create-your-own-sliding-divs-with-jQuery.aspx) [ PS: The name is 'Vishu' :) ]

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#left").click( function() {
        var pos = $("#content").css('marginLeft','0px');
        $("#content").scrollLeft(pos);
    });
    $("#right").click( function() {
        var pos = $("#content").css('marginLeft', '-164px');
        $("#content").scrollLeft(pos);
    });
});
```

Change Marginleft on left click to 0 and on rightclick to -164px